# Different results for query on mysql 5.6 and 5.7

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I have a laravel application that was running an elqouent query with a whereHas method.  The method was not returning any data on a virtual machine running mysql 5.7 but was working on 5.6.  I got the raw query out of eloquent, here's what it is:

```
select * from `threads` where `id` = 5053 and exists (select * from `users` inner join `threads_users` on `users`.`id` = `threads_users`.`user_id` where `threads_users`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `user_id` = 296) limit 1
```

When I run this sql in mysql 5.6 it will return a single row but when I run it on mysql 5.7 it returns nothing.  Is there some feature that was removed between these versions that would break this query?

Comment: Break it down into two queries, execute them separately and assert whether your databases indeed contain the same data.

Comment: I tried doing it where I explicitly put the thread id in the subquery and it works on the 5.7 mysql instance:
    select * from `threads` where `id` = 5053 and exists (select * from `users` inner join `threads_users` on `users`.`id` = `threads_users`.`user_id` where `threads_users`.`thread_id` = 5053 and `user_id` = 296) limit 1